# Implement zxing-2.0 into my android app

Tags: android, zxing

So i'm trying to implement that into my app, however the problem is that it doesn't work as a solo application so it crush evrytime i start it. I do evry thing as in followed tutorial http://damianflannery.wordpress.com/2011/06/13/integrate-zxing-barcode-scanner-into-your-android-app-natively-using-eclipse/ however, it somehow doesn't work. So i tryied to start the captureActivity as application rather than library, and it crashes on start when it tries to do that:

```
 private static final Set<ResultMetadataType> DISPLAYABLE_METADATA_TYPES =
  EnumSet.of(ResultMetadataType.ISSUE_NUMBER,
             ResultMetadataType.SUGGESTED_PRICE,
             ResultMetadataType.ERROR_CORRECTION_LEVEL,
             ResultMetadataType.POSSIBLE_COUNTRY);
```

That leads to the problem that i didn't compile core.jar correctly. However i can't see where would i do a mistake. I run ant -f in core directory, and it gives me core.jar. Any ideas what could i do?

edit: logcat:

```
 01-06 02:07:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1629): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
 01-06 02:07:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1629): java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
 01-06 02:07:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):    at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
 01-06 02:07:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1409)
 01-06 02:07:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):    at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
 01-06 02:07:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1561)
 01-06 02:07:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1663)
 01-06 02:07:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
 01-06 02:07:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:931)
 01-06 02:07:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
 01-06 02:07:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
 01-06 02:07:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
 01-06 02:07:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
 01-06 02:07:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
 01-06 02:07:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
 01-06 02:07:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
 01-06 02:07:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 01-06 02:07:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1629): Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.zxing.ResultMetadataType
 01-06 02:07:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):    at com.google.zxing.client.android.CaptureActivity.<clinit>(CaptureActivity.java:107)
 01-06 02:07:08.280: E/AndroidRuntime(1629):    ... 15 more
 01-06 02:07:08.740: E/GoKeyboard(1442): error setSuggestions isNotInput()!
 01-06 02:07:09.140: E/GoKeyboard(1442): error setSuggestions isNotInput()!
 01-06 02:07:11.600: E/GoKeyboard(1442): error setSuggestions isNotInput()!
 01-06 02:07:11.600: E/GoKeyboard(1442): error setSuggestions isNotInput()!
```

Now i downloaded the core from here http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.google.zxing/core/2.0 and used it and steal same mistake so it must be something else...

Comment: do you have the barcode scanner application installed in your phone?]

Comment: i didnt have it before but when i start that app it install barcode scanner, but when i start it, it crash.

Comment: now i tried that with zxing2.1 and yet it's not working :S I've got the same problem...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Properties -> Java Build Path -> "Order and Export"

Then order the core.jar to the first position and select it!

you must clean your project after your operation. Project -> clean

That solves the problem. I hope it saves somebody's time.

Answer (score 0):

The main problem with the last version of ADT is that the resource constants cannot be used inside a switch-case statement. The solution is to follow the instructions found in this URL:
http://tools.android.com/tips/non-constant-fields
on the switch-case statements indicating an error and converting them to if-else.
This way worked for me with zxing2.1.

Comment: By converting Swith cases into if else really solved my problem thanx...!